# Check Subscribers of a Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to check the Consumers that subscribed to a topic called "foo". I don't have the Kafka Consumer Information. Is there anyway with which we can check the Number of consumers that are consuming from the topic "foo"?

Answer (score 1):

For consumer group members, you can always list the clients using `kafka-consumer-groups` script e.g. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_lag

But in general scenario, with consumers that *are not* members of CG, this is not trivially possible - basically every consumer periodically sends a `FetchRequest` to brokers, and brokers just reply.

Extremely overkill solution for that would be to capture the traffic between brokers & clients and parse the payloads (with http://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html#The_Messages_Fetch). Every fetch request contains `client-id`, and that can be used for identifying consumers.